# ScrollView with Autolayout issue Xcode 11.X

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout, scrollview

I am using scrollView with autolayout in Xcode 11.5 and Swift 5, but i have some problems with the **contentSize** of the **scrollView**.The problem is that the **contentView.bounds.size** is returning bigger value than screen size. I want it to work on older versions of iOS like ios 10 so Content Layout and Frame Layout is not possible.

In Storyboard I have the next one:

UIView

---ScrollView (pinned **leading**, **trailing**, **top** and **bottom** to **0** to **superview**)

-------- ContentView (pinned **leading**, **trailing**, **top** and **bottom** to **0** to **scrollView** and **equal Height** and **Width to UIView**)

---------------- *UIImage, UIButton, UILabel, etc.

[MyProject - testing scrollView (ios target 10.0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhDCh.png)

[MyProject - testing scrollView (ios target 10.0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyNIh.png)

[TesstProject - testing scrollView (ios target 13.0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vj4c.png)

*Constraints are the same

Any help or suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the priority of `contentView`'s `height constraint` to 250 in `Interface Builder`. It should be breakable. And there is no reason to override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` you should remove this.

[image: Interface Builder]

[How to configure a UIScrollView with Auto Layout in Interface Builder.](https://medium.com/@pradeep_chauhan/how-to-configure-a-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder-218dcb4022d7)

---

You should set `ContentView`'s height and width to `Super View` which is top of the hierarchy

[image: Edited ScreenShot]

Comment: could you please share your `Interface Builder` configuration? I mean constraints and view hierarchy.

Comment: please see reviewed post with images

Comment: you should set width and height of view(Content View) which is under the scrollView to superView's (which is top of the hierarchy under the Episode Detail View Controller) width and height. As I understand now you've set the height and width of the scrollView to the view but you should set Content View's width and height to the top View.

Comment: Actually they are the other way...the way you said...contentView has equal height and width to superview and not scrollView? And i cannot understand why is the scrollView is visible at top(as per screenshot) in MyProject